# Disable connection tracking with UFW for port 80

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, ufw

During load testing my server is dropping packets due to "connection tracking" way before it's running out of resources. I'm using Ubuntu Jaunty with ufw. In my syslog I get:

`ip_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.`

I looked at upping the max connection table size, but I don't know of an advantage for tracking these connections on these ports. I would like to know how to use ufw to tell it not to track requests to port 80 and 443.

**Clarifying**

- No natting needed, it's just a web
  server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection tracking is an on/off switch, you cannot selectively disable it for some kind of traffic. You should increase the number of connections tracked via varius nf_conntrack_max options under `/proc/sys/net`. You can also consider enabling syncookies to reduce congestion effects.

*Edit*: It seems that iptables with `-j NOTRACK` allows you to disable connection tracking selectively.

Comment: How would I disable it completely?

Comment: You can rmmod the nf_conntrack module after flushing firewall rules.

Comment: That is partially incorrect. You can disable it for certain interfaces or ports using iptables, see below.

Answer (score 4):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j NOTRACK 
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j NOTRACK
```

will disable connection tracking just for these ports.

Comment: On an Ubuntu 10.04 server, that errored out, but this did work:
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i lo -j NOTRACK

Answer (score -1):

Do you NAT? I believe without ip_conntrack you can't NAT.

Comment: I don't use nat - just a web server