# ufw without connection tracking

Tags: iptables, ufw, nf-conntrack

I am using ufw on a high traffic webserver (lot of http/https traffic) on ubuntu (12.04 or 14.04).

I tried tuning kernel parameters related to connection tracking with [some success](https://serverfault.com/questions/726287/ubuntu-14-04-tcp-established-hash-table-entries/726316#726316).

However, thinking about it, I don't do NAT, therefore I don't think I need connection tracking at least for the connections on port 80 or 443.

I tried following the directions from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/43679/disable-connection-tracking-with-ufw-for-port-80) with adaptations, that is:

```
sudo iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j NOTRACK
```

and my raw table looks like:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
NOTRACK    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

To test that it all works, I request an nginx instance on the machine using wrk using 3 threads and 1000 connections .

```
wrk -t 3 -c 1000 "http://<server_ip>/"
```

As those are not supposed to be tracked, I should not see them on the conntrack count

However, I do...

```
sudo sysctl -A | grep net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 1035
```

I can clearly see this value going up and down as I run the test.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/72366/how-do-i-disable-the-nf-conntrack-kernel-module-in-centos-5-3-without-recompilin ?

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for, as I want to disable them only on 80 and 443. This will disable connection tracking entirely.  I will give it a shot if I can't find anything else though. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You need an OUTPUT rule, too.

```
-t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j NOTRACK
-t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j NOTRACK
```